# Изменить ключ в многомерном массиве

Tags: php

Есть многомерный массив:

```
Array 
( 
    [0] => Array 
    ( 
        [0] => msi 
        [1] => im
        [2] => rec
        [3] => orig_tor
    ) 

    [1] => Array 
    ( 
        [0] => 911
        [1] => 2150 
        [2] => 10 
        [3] => 7
    ) 
)
```

Нужно изменить ключ массива (переименовать, по сути поменять местами) `array[0][1]` на `array[0][2]` и `array[0][2]` на `array[0][1]` и так далее для каждого вложенного массива для ключей [1] и [2].

Comment: Поменяйте значения этих ключей местами.

Comment: Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Можете использовать list() http://php.net/manual/ru/function.list.php для обмена значений без дополнительных переменных.

Answer (score 1):

```
$array=[....];
foreach($array as &$inner){
    $temp = $inner[2];
    $inner[2] = $inner[1];
    $inner[1] = $temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделал по рекомендации @Visman

```
$result=[....];

    $keys = array_keys($result);
    for($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++) {

        foreach($result[$keys[$i]] as $key => $value) {
list($result[$keys[$i]][3], $result[$keys[$i]][2]) = array($result[$keys[$i]][2], $result[$keys[$i]][3]);

        }
    }
```

Comment: С list надо быть крайне осторожным. Поиграйтесь версиями PHP вот в этом примере и ужаснитесь http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/68329d8d8d5c9fe86bccc237f1637ca17afeb1a6 (так, как в примере, делать нельзя если что)

Comment: Да странный какой-то результат получается по вашему примеру. Интересно почему.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/migration70.incompatible.php   раздел "Изменение в обработке list() "